# SSIS Package connect to Readonly Database with Availability Group

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, alwayson

I am trying to connect to a secondary server in an availability group to use the readonly version of the database with an OLE DB connection in an SSIS package and can't seem to do it.  That simple.  Can it be done and if so how?

Edited:
Forgot to add that we want to be able to use a project parameter to pass in the connection string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I just figured it out by accident.  See if you can spot the difference.

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;ApplicationIntent=Readonly;

Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Intent=Readonly;
```

That's right.  I didn't have a space in "Application Intent".  My bad.  Sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: ODBC uses ApplicationIntent (no space). OLEDB uses Application Intent (space). That probably lead to your (understandable) confusion.